# Why NSMutableDictionary is losing data?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using `NSMutableDictionary`. Declare it using property as follows:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *books;
```

In the method, I am assigning it values.

```
- (void)setUpBooks {
     if (self.books == nil){
         self.books = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
     }
     // my code goes here...
     [self.books setObject:book forKey:key];

     NSLog(@"books : %@",self.books);
     NSLog(@"books Count : %d",[self.books count]);
 }
```

In this `NSLog` it's showing correct values. But when I tried to use `self.books` in another method its showing `null`. I don't know where my data is losing.

Comment: have you synthesized the object?

Comment: @Sunny: No need to synthesize properties in iOS 6

Comment: i think nothing wrong with the above code... can u post where your getting null and how your accessing the dictionary

Comment: may be somewhere else you are initializing that array once agian but not sure.

Comment: before NSLog print the reference count of self.books and check it. If it's 0 means the memory is getting released some where.

Comment: There's no way to help you without setting full code

Comment: @Mohan - Advising someone to use retainCount? Hello? Welcome to 2013!

Comment: What method do you call setUpBooks for the first time? This should be viewDidLoad else the property may not have been initialized before other methods attempt to access the property. Additionally, using iOS 6 automatically renames the NSMutableDictionary to _books (not books) when using the @property declaration. This may mean that you are not properly accessing the dictionary.

Comment: @Abizern - I am not using ARC.

Comment: You would have to drop the self. Syntax. If you opt for the _books syntax.

Comment: @Matt, but the OP is using self.books, and that's fine for accessing his property. The property isn't renamed, it's the backing ivar that's _books.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the *same instance* of your class when you access `self.books` later? Try to add `NSLog(@"instance: %p", self)` to both `setUpBooks` and your other method where you access the property.

Comment: @Midhun MP, whether it is needed or not in this case he should "try" with synthesizing the property. I also think that may work.

Answer (score -1):

Easy way to use NSMutableDictionay.

Try this,

```
NSMutableDictionary * books = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

NSDictionary *book = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Value",@"BOOK_KEY", nil];

[books addEntriesFromDictionary:book];
```

Hope it's help you.

Comment: It's no different from what he is doing now except that you are including the setup in the initialisation.